# moving an attribute to a child element xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been trying to move an attribute from one element to another but instead it creates another child element.

I have the following

```
<wrapper>
 <Person ID="1">
  <Person InfoName="bob" Gender="male" />
  <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="book"/>
  <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="shoes"/>
 </Person>
 <Person ID="2">
  <Person InfoName="Jane" Gender="female"/>
  <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="pen"/>
  <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="hat"/>
 </Person>
</wrapper>
```

and I need to have the following (I'm not precious about keeping  as all the records will have the ID):

```
<wrapper>
 <Person ID="1">
  <Person InfoName="bob" Gender="male" ID = "1"/>
  <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="book" ID="1"/>
  <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="shoes" ID="1"/>
 </Person>
 <Person ID="2">
  <Person InfoName="Jane" Gender="female" ID="2"/>
  <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="pen" ID="2"/>
  <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="hat" ID="2"/>
 </Person>
</wrapper>
```

I have tried several different XSLTs with varying degrees of success. The following creates a new child node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[@ID]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'ID']" />
         <xsl:element name="{name()}ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
         </xsl:element>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it is appreciated.... the purpose of the transform was so I could import and XML file into access for further scrutiny, I have since used XML Spy to do this for me and as such the XSLT is no longer required...

Comment: I.Alam, see a solution in which the added `ID` attribute is the last -- as wanted in your question. The other two solutions place it as the first ...

Comment: The XML specification states explicitly that the order of attributes is not significant. The XSLT processor may output them in any order. Trying to control the order through the XSLT stylesheet is pointless; what works with one processor may not work with another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Take care of a valid xml. Attributes must be Key-Value-pair e.g. `info="a"` (value must be in `"`). XML is case-sensitiv.

(2) Your solution is much simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wrapper/Person/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ../@ID"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Select your elements to copy into via `wrapper/Person/*` and grep the attribute `ID` of parent via `..`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it is appreciated.... the purpose of the transform was so I could import and XML file into access for further scrutiny, I have since used XML Spy to do this for me and as such the XSLT is no longer required

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|../@ID|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **well-formed** input:

```
<Wrapper>
<Person ID ="1">
 <Person Name="bob" Gender="male" />
 <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="book"/>
 <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="shoes"/>
</Person>

<Person ID ="2">
 <Person Name="Jane" Gender="female"/>
 <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="pen"/>
 <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="hat"/>
</Person>
</Wrapper>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wrapper>
   <Person ID="1">
      <Person ID="1" Name="bob" Gender="male"/>
      <Purchase ID="1" Reference="1" Item="book"/>
      <Purchase ID="1" Reference="2" Item="shoes"/>
   </Person>
   <Person ID="2">
      <Person ID="2" Name="Jane" Gender="female"/>
      <Purchase ID="2" Reference="1" Item="pen"/>
      <Purchase ID="2" Reference="2" Item="hat"/>
   </Person>
</Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the only solution so far, which places the `ID` attribute last -- as wanted:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../@ID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<wrapper>
    <Person ID="1">
        <Person InfoName="bob" Gender="male" />
        <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="book"/>
        <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="shoes"/>
    </Person>
    <Person ID="2">
        <Person InfoName="Jane" Gender="female"/>
        <Purchase Reference = "1" Item="pen"/>
        <Purchase Reference = "2" Item="hat"/>
    </Person>
</wrapper>
```

**The exact (not like the results from other solutions) wanted result is produced**:

```
<wrapper>
   <Person ID="1">
      <Person InfoName="bob" Gender="male" ID="1"/>
      <Purchase Reference="1" Item="book" ID="1"/>
      <Purchase Reference="2" Item="shoes" ID="1"/>
   </Person>
   <Person ID="2">
      <Person InfoName="Jane" Gender="female" ID="2"/>
      <Purchase Reference="1" Item="pen" ID="2"/>
      <Purchase Reference="2" Item="hat" ID="2"/>
   </Person>
</wrapper>
```